# Java scanner - read in each line as a finite data set

Tags: java, linked-list, java.util.scanner, tokenize

I am writing a program for class that takes in a text file, containing something such as the following:

1 3 2 4 3 2

1 2 2 7 3 2

add

I want to copy each of the first two lines into separate Polynomials 
(LinkedLists).  I can get the scanner to tokenize all the ints in the entire file and copy everything into one Polynomial, but I want to read in the first line of ints, stop, and then copy the second line of ints into a separate Polynomial.  I don't know how to halt the scanner at the end of each line. Any suggestions?

Here is my code (relevant portion is in main at the bottom).

```
public class Polynomial {

private Term head;  //header before first item
private Term tail;  //trailer after last item
private int size; // number of elements in Polynomial

//constructor of empty Polynomial

public Polynomial(){
    head = new Term();
    tail = new Term();
    head.next = tail;
    tail.prev = head;       
} // end empty Polynomial constructor


//Term class
private static class Term {
    private int exp;
    private double coeff;
    private Term next;
    private Term prev;

    //constructor of empty Term
    public Term() {
        this.exp = -1;
        this.coeff = 0.0;
    }// end empty Term constructor

    //constructor of term with exponent and coefficient
    public Term(int e, double c){
        this.exp = e;
        this.coeff = c; 
    }//end constructor of term with exponent and coefficient

    //getters of exponent and coefficient
    public int getExp() {return exp;}
    public double getCoeff() {return coeff;}

    //setters of exponent and coefficient
    public void setExp(int e) {exp = e;}
    public void setCoeff(double c) {coeff = c;}

    //getters of pointers of Polynomial terms
    public Term getPrev() {return prev;}
    public Term getNext() {return next;}

    //setters of pointers of Polynomial terms
    public void setPrev(Term p) {prev=p;}
    public void setNext(Term n) {next=n;}       
}// end Term class

//addterm method
public void addTerm(int e, double c){
    Term last = tail.prev;
    Term temp = new Term(e, c);
    temp.next = tail;
    temp.prev = last;
    tail.prev = temp;
    last.next = temp;
    size++; 
}// end addTerm method

public int size() {return size;}

public boolean isEmpty() {return size==0;}  



public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    FileReader fin = new FileReader("Test.txt");
    Scanner src = new Scanner(fin);
    Scanner lineTokenizer = new Scanner(src.nextLine());
    int lineNum = 0;

    Polynomial p1 = new Polynomial();

        while (src.hasNextLine()) {            

            lineNum++;

            while (lineTokenizer.hasNextInt()){
            p1.addTerm(lineTokenizer.nextInt(), lineTokenizer.nextInt()) ;

        }

        lineTokenizer.close();  
    src.close();

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use BufferedReader and then split lines to separate numbers:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Test.txt"));
String line;
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] nums = line.split(" ");
    //get each num from nums and cast it to integer using Integer.parseInt()
}
```